# Multi action on one button with javascript routine

Tags: javascript

How can I set up "click action" on two( or three) objects when press a button with javascript?
Thank you so much

Comment: Please be more concrete. Do you need a solution for plain JavaScript or with the help of JS library (e.g. jQuery)? What kind of markup do you have? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `click()` method of other clickable elements in button's `onclick` event, e.g.

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Button 1" onclick="clickAllbuttons()" />

<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Button 2" onclick="alert('Button 2 is clicked!')" />
<input id="Button3" type="button" value="Button 3" onclick="alert('Button 3 is clicked!')"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function clickAllbuttons() {

         alert('Button 1 is clicked!')

         document.getElementById('Button2').click();
         document.getElementById('Button3').click();
     }

 </script>
```

Here 3 buttons is defined in HTML markup, but if you click Button 1 - Button 2 and Button 3 also get clicked